# Update query that handles duplicates and increment operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb

**Background:**

1. I have an update query on collection called `alerts` that runs each
   time a "flow" is received.
2. I have an array of objects in my alert's document called
   `blacklistedCommunication`.

**What should happen:**

When a new flow arrives, then the `alerts` doc is updated **only** if the flow's `client_addr` and `server_addr` are not already present in `blacklistedCommuication`. While at the same time, if we do find duplicates, it should only increment the `flowCount`.

**The current query:**

The below update query works to push new objects to `blacklistedCommunication` object if it's not present already.
However, if it is indeed present, it will not update the `flowCount`

How can I incorporate this logic into the query? Do I need to write a separate update query in case of duplicates?

```
alerts.update({
       alertLevel: "orgLevelAlert",
       alertCategory: "blacklistedServersViolationAlert",
       alertState: "open",
       'blacklistedCommunication.client': {
           $ne: flow.netflow.client_addr
       },
       // 'blacklistedCommunication.server': {
       //     $ne: flow.netflow.server_addr
       // }  
    }, {
       $set: {
           "misc.updatedTime": new Date()
       },
       $inc: {
           flowCount: 1
       },
       $push: {
           blacklistedCommunication: {
               client: flow.netflow.client_addr,
               server: flow.netflow.server_addr
           }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of `$push`. It will ensure unique `{client:*,server:*}` object within `blacklistedCommunication` and will always update `flowCount`:

```
alerts.update({
   alertLevel: "orgLevelAlert",
   alertCategory: "blacklistedServersViolationAlert",
   alertState: "open"
}, {
   $set: {
       "misc.updatedTime": new Date()
   },
   $inc: {
       flowCount: 1
   },
   $addToSet: {
       blacklistedCommunication: {
           client: flow.netflow.client_addr,
           server: flow.netflow.server_addr
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was just wondering. This update will run extremely frequently, as much as a couple of times a second. Would it be ok to fire so many updates to mongo? Or should I be needing to handle the uniqueness check in js instead?

Comment: Hmm, I must misread the original question, but I as far as I understand you need to update flowCount in any case. Could you confirm it it please, as the follow up question doesn't make sense in this scenario.

Comment: My bad. As for the question, your answer works perfectly. Ignore my followup question.